# Creating a VLOOKUP that references another sheet, but the sheet name is the content of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

I'm trying to create a `VLOOKUP` for billing purposes. I need to have the number of last month's documents in the current month's billing information. I have the `VLOOKUP` working with no problems, but I want to name the sheet after the month and have the `VLOOKUP` reference a cell for the sheet name. So far I have:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B1,"!")),A:G,7,FALSE)
```

where `A4` is  Project Name
`B1` is Previous month (ie July2014)
`A:G` is the table array on the previous month's sheet
in which it is column `7` that contains the closing document count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,INDIRECT(B1&"!A:G"),7,FALSE)
```

though you might want to consider using named ranges of Workbook scope.